# Authentication library for Phoenix

Tags: authentication, elixir, phoenix-framework

I found myself implementing a cookie based authentication with Phoenix. As much as I enjoyed toying with the concept, I think a library should do this job.

What are my options in Elixir/Phoenix?

Comment: Lots of options there.  Really broad question.  Vote to close.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Lots of options is also a bad situations when trying to build your stack. I'll refrase the question.

Answer (score 2):

Personally i like https://github.com/elixircnx/openmaize

But you can check more at https://github.com/h4cc/awesome-elixir#authorization

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in one of the previous questions on the sbuject, I think it's more reliable to write one yourself at this point. It's rather trivial because Phoenix and Elixir give you everything you may need. And as a bonus, you will learn how some things are done under the hood, if you don't know yet.